# Help with Jagged Array needed, getting IQueryable results into an array

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Does anyone know how I can get my results currently in qry IQueryable object into a jagged array in the format:

```
        series:
             [{
                name: '2',
                data: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
                    }, {
                name: '3',
                data: [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 3, 0]

                }]
```

My problem is the code I have at the moment wraps double quotes around the 12 element data part, i.e. it looks like this in the debugger on client side:

?result[0]
{...}
    [0]: "2"
    [1]: "[0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0]"
?result[1]
{...}
    [0]: "3"
    [1]: "[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]"

The problem is my array contains a single string element rather than an array of 12 numbers.

Here is my controller code that at the moment returns the 12 number part as one big string :

```
        var qry = from i in _db.Complaints
             where i.Site.SiteDescription.Contains(searchTextSite)
                  && (i.Raised >= startDate && i.Raised <= endDate)
            group i by i.ComplaintNatureTypeId.ToString()
            into grp select new 
            {
                Type = grp.Key,
                Count = "[" + grp.Where(c => c.Raised.Month == 1).Count() + "," + 
                        grp.Where(c => c.Raised.Month == 2).Count() + "," +
                        grp.Where(c => c.Raised.Month == 3).Count() + "," + 
                        grp.Where(c => c.Raised.Month == 4).Count() + "," +
                        grp.Where(c => c.Raised.Month == 5).Count() + "," + 
                        grp.Where(c => c.Raised.Month == 6).Count() + "," +
                        grp.Where(c => c.Raised.Month == 7).Count() + "," + 
                        grp.Where(c => c.Raised.Month == 8).Count() + "," +
                        grp.Where(c => c.Raised.Month == 9).Count() + "," + 
                        grp.Where(c => c.Raised.Month == 10).Count() + "," +
                        grp.Where(c => c.Raised.Month == 11).Count() + "," + 
                        grp.Where(c => c.Raised.Month == 12).Count() + "]"

            };


        return Json(qry.ToArray(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Comment: I think i need to create an array and loop qry object but the problem is the array of 12 numbers is a string. Tied in knots with this anyone suggest an approach, many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass an object and `Json` will serialize it to a JSON string.

```
Count = new int[] {
   grp.Where(c => c.Raised.Month == 1).Count(),
   grp.Where(c => c.Raised.Month == 2).Count(),
   grp.Where(c => c.Raised.Month == 3).Count(),
   grp.Where(c => c.Raised.Month == 4).Count(),
   grp.Where(c => c.Raised.Month == 5).Count(), 
   grp.Where(c => c.Raised.Month == 6).Count(),
   grp.Where(c => c.Raised.Month == 7).Count(), 
   grp.Where(c => c.Raised.Month == 8).Count(),
   grp.Where(c => c.Raised.Month == 9).Count(), 
   grp.Where(c => c.Raised.Month == 10).Count(),
   grp.Where(c => c.Raised.Month == 11).Count(), 
   grp.Where(c => c.Raised.Month == 12).Count()
}
```

Or you could do something like:

```
Count = Enumerable.Range(1, 12).Select(x => grp.Where(c => c.Raised.Month == x).Count())
```

Answer (score 0):

You are creating the count property as a string, should it not be an array:

```
Count = new [] {
grp.Where(c => c.Raised.Month == 1).Count(),
grp.Where(c => c.Raised.Month == 2).Count(),
...
grp.Where(c => c.Raised.Month == 12).Count()
}
```